# Four integers that satisfy $a+b+c+d\; =\; -3$ and $a^{3}+b^{3}+c^{3}+d^{3}\; =\; 3$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

> Find a set of 4 integers that satisfy $$a+b+c+d\; =\; -3$$ and $$a^{3}+b^{3}+c^{3}+d^{3}\; =\; 3$$

I am really not sure how to proceed. I tried letting $d = -c$ to see if that would yield a possible solution but it did not work. Further, trying to cube the first equation just yields a big mess. I think there might be a way to factor using sum of cubes and make substitutions that could simplify it but I don't have any insight as to how to approach it...

Comment: Regarding the insight part: generally integers in 3 variables (your case) means finding integer points on surfaces (Sometimes you can simplify the equations, which is what you should always try first). This is quite difficult if you want the full solution; you need to know some Arithmetic Geometry.  For some examples and references you can look up on "rational points on cubic surfaces" (or integral points). If you just want to find some solutions, you can try solving in $\pmod p$ for many primes and combining solutions in Chinese remainder theorem. This helps to exhaust the small solutions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, there is a solution with $a=b=c$.

EDIT:
With $c = -a + k$ and $d = -b-k-3$, the system becomes 
$$ k a^2  - k^2 a  + 3 k^2 + 9 k + 10 = (k+3) b^2 + (k+3)^2 b $$
which has infinitely many integer solutions for some integer values of $k$.
For example, with $k = 2$, writing $a = A/4 + 1$ and $b = (B-5)/2$ yields
$$   A^2 = 10 B^2 + 86 $$
(where we want solutions where $A$ is divisible by $4$).  One solution is $A = 24, B = 7$ (corresponding to $a = 7, b = 1$).  From the theory of
Pell equations, given one solution $(A,B)$ of $A^2 = 10 B^2 + 86$, another is
$(A' = 19 A + 60 B, B' = 6 A + 19 B)$.  In terms of $a$ and $b$, the mapping
is $$(a,b) \to (a',b') = (19 a + 30 b + 57, 12 a + 19 b + 33)$$
Repeating the mapping gives us an infinite family of solutions
$$ \eqalign{ [7, 1,& -5, -6]\cr
[220, 136,& -218, -141]\cr
[8317, 5257,& -8315, -5262]\cr
[315790, 199720,& -315788, -199725]\cr
[11991667, 7584193,& -11991665, -7584198]}$$
etc.

Comment: Namely: (-2,-2,-2,3)

Answer (score 3):

Those work, as do

-8,-8,3,10 and -6,-5,1,7

Comment: How did you obtain these?

Comment: I wrote a program. ;-)   There must be an intelligent way of obtaining these, but I'm too tired right now.

Comment: I wonder if there are more. I've only found the solutions we've already discussed with $-50\le a,b,c,d\le 50$,

Comment: Also $[-218, -141, 136, 220]$ and $[-335,-215,210,337]$

Comment: a=-2888 b=-2732 c=2707 d=2910<br>
a=-2675 b=-2633 c=2586 d=2719<br>
a=-335 b=-215 c=210 d=337<br>
a=-218 b=-141 c=136 d=220<br>
a=-8 b=-8 c=3 d=10<br>
a=-6 b=-5 c=1 d=7<br>
a=-2 b=-2 c=-2 d=3

Answer (score 2):

$(3, -2, -2, -2 ) $ works. Trial and error.